# Split pandas column objects with no str attributes

Tags: python, pandas, object, split, attributes

I am attempting to `.split()` cells in a table that has multiple values. Then I want to stack those split values into a single column.

I keep getting : ***AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'***

1. Some of the columns will have the same names/labels
2. The values will be mixed between str, flt, int, etc
3. There will be missing values
4. I have this table saved as a .csv

Example Table:

**(Original Table)**

```
List , A,  A , B     , B , A , C  
row 1,joey,mike,henry,albert    ,sherru,tomkins  
row 2, ,pig|soap    , ,123, ,  ,  
row 3,yes, , , and|5.3|7, , ,     
row 4, ,new york|up, , , , ,                  
row 5,bubbles, ,movie, , , ,
```

**(Modified Table)**

```
List | Value | Category  
row 1,joey, A  
row 1,mike,A  
row 1,henry,B  
row 1,albert,B  
row 1,sherru,A  
row 1,tomkins,C  
row 2,pig,A  
row 2,soap,A  
row 2,123,B  
row 3,yes,A  
row 3,and,B  
row 3,5.3,B  
...   
row 5,movie,B
```

This is the code I am using, I am new to python/pandas so its not that great:

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')  

df2 = df.A.str.split('|').apply(pd.series)  
df2.index = df.set_index([List]).index  
df2.stack().reset_index([List])
```

Comment: Your CSV file is invalid: different rows have different number of columns. Could you please format it appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) as first step and add parameter `expand=True` to [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `DataFrame`:

```
df2 = df.set_index('List').A.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index()
```

You get error because dupes in columns names, so `df.A` return all columns `A` as `DataFrame`.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. upgrade pandas, because [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) in newer versions manage dupes - add `.1`, `.2` ([pandas 0.19+](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#read-csv-has-improved-support-for-duplicate-column-names))
2. change columns names by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

---

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = df.columns + s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str).radd('.').replace('.0','')
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})
df.columns = list('AABBCD')
print (df)
   A  A  B  B  C  D
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = df.columns + s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str).radd('.').replace('.0','')
print (df)
   A  A.1  B  B.1  C  D
0  a    4  7    1  5  a
1  b    5  8    3  3  a
2  c    4  9    5  6  a
3  d    5  4    7  9  b
4  e    5  2    1  2  b
5  f    4  3    0  4  b
```

Comment: I am still getting the attribute error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Any ideas?

Comment: @M-M - yes, I know. There is problem `A` column name is duplicated. Can you upgrade pandas? Becouse in new versions `pd.read_csv` change `A, A` columns to `A, A.1` - rename columns names.